# Die ganze polnische Inteligenzija kam in einem kleinen Dorf – Józefów – an

Tags: verb, preposition

> Die ganze polnische Intelligenz kam in einem kleinen Dorf – Józefów – an, um sein Ableben zu betrauern.

Habe ich das richtige Verb und die richtige Präposition benutzt?

Comment: Damit die Frage zur Seite paßt, muß es schon um ein konkretes Problem gehen.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Leider fehlt in der gestellten Frage, welches Verb oder welche Präposition falsch sein könnten - und warum dem so sei. (ansonsten kann ich nix falsches entdecken).

Answer (score 2):

Grammatikalisch ist der Satz richtig, wenn es um die Trauerfeier für eine männliche Person geht (oder jemand/etwas anderes, der/das grammatisch maskulin/neutral ist). Als Verb wäre *zusammenkommen* allerdings besser geeignet, da *ankommen* wirklich nur das erste *Ankommen* (z.B. vom Aussteigen aus dem Zug bis zum Absteigen in einem Hotel) beschreibt und nicht *dasein* bedeutet. Also:

> Die ganze polnische Intelligenz kam in einem kleinen Dorf – Józefów – zusammen, um sein Ableben zu betrauern.

Flüssiger wäre vielleicht noch

> kam in dem kleinen Dorf Józefów zusammen

oder

> kam in einem kleinen Dorf namens Józefów zusammen.

Statt *kam … zusammen* kann auch *fand sich … zusammen* benutzt werden, was unter Umständen etwas gehobener klingen kann.

Comment: Genau genommen weiß man nur, dass es ein Lebewesen ist. Es könnte auch ein Hund sein, auch wenn das weit hergeholt ist, aber es kommt ja darauf an, wie auf dieses Lebewesen zuletzt referiert wurde, "1941 starb das letzte Mitglied des polnischen Lyrikzirkels." Hier hätten wir ein sächliches Geschlecht, sprachlich, aber auch daraus ergibt sich "sein Ableben". Bei "... starb die letzte Mathematikkoryphäe" könnte die Person nach wie vor ein Mann sein, das Geschlecht von Koryphäe ist aber weiblich und dann müsste "ihr Ableben" - "Wessen Ableben?" "Das Ableben der Mathematikkoryphäe" stehen.

Comment: @userunknown Danke für den Hinweis, habe ihn eingearbeitet!

Comment: Vielleicht dem Anlass und der vermutlichen Textgattung noch angemessener: *fand sich zusammen* (statt *kam zusammen*).

Comment: Danke @ChristianGeiselmann, habe den Vorschlag ergänzt